# Apache .htaccess to hide both .php and .html extentions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What lines should I add to remove both `.html` and `.php` extensions from my site?

I use this for just the `.html` part:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://jobler.ro/} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://jobler.ro/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I need for both file type extensions to be hidden from the same domain.

Answer (score 6):

I know its late to answer but I giving it since it can be useful to someone :)

```
#Remove php extension
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#Remove html extension
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

This will remove both php and html extension from your files and works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You would want to test whether the file with `.html` or `.php` exists, and then redirect to such file if so.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.((html)|(php))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([^.]+)$  $1 [R,L]
```

Comment: @Blazer, hey, since it all works, any chance you can click to accept the answer? :-)

Comment: @Blazer, since this works perfectly well, any chance you can click the accept button, so that both you and me get the points for the hard work? thanks!