# mod_rewrite not working htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a [website](http://dundaah.com) with 11 sub-domains.I have one main `htaccess` file in the `public_html` root folder that has the common shared traits like `cache` etc. I have separate `htaccess` files in each of the sub-domain root folders where I use `mod_rewrite` however I can't get it to rewrite the URL. I'm trying to change it from `dundaah.com/days/content.php?day=thur` to a much cleaner `dundaah.com/thursday` and for the sub-domains `music.dundaah.com/days/content.php?day=thur` to a preferred `music.dundaah.com/thursday`. My 1st researched code so far only gets me to the URL `dundaah.com/day/thur` and the 2nd to `dundaah.com/thursday` still gives me a 404 error. I have not changed the internal links of the site, is this a prolem? Could anyone help? Thanks

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  Options +FollowSymlinks
  
  # enable the rewrite engine
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/days/content.php
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^day=([a-z]+)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /days/%1? [R,L]

  # or for individual pages 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/days/content.php
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^day=thur$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /thursday? [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does the url example.com/thursday work if you type it directly in your browser address bar?

Comment: no not while using the above code

Comment: Each and every day needs a different rule Or you can use `RewriteMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, I was the one using a bad folder directory system in my website. This is the one is was using

`public_html(www directory)
    -index.php
        -vidz(sub-domain)
            -index.php
            -days
                -_imports
                -css
                -js
                -php
                -content.php
                -contact.php`

This is my upgraded system

`public_html(www directory)
    -index.php
        -vidz(sub-domain)
            -index.php
            -content.php
            -contact.php
            -assets
                -_imports
                -css
                -js
                -php`

Which makes it possible to have the links as `<a href='monday'>Mon</a>` and use the `.htaccess` redirect rules below.

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On   
    RewriteRule ^monday$ content.php?day=mon [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^tuesday$ content.php?day=tue [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^wednesday$ content.php?day=wed [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^thursday$ content.php?day=thur [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^friday$ content.php?day=fri [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^saturday$ content.php?day=sat [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^sunday$ content.php?day=sun [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks to all who answered! It helped me realize this.

Answer (score 2):

This will make `/thursday` work (and all the other days), put it in your main `.htaccess` and in your sub-domain ones. It will also redirect your old URLs to the new ones.

It will only work if you are on Apache 2.4 or later. Let me know if you're not and I'll update the answer.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect old URLs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =day=mon
RewriteRule ^days/content\.php$ /monday [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =day=tue
RewriteRule ^days/content\.php$ /tuesday [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =day=wed
RewriteRule ^days/content\.php$ /wednesday [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =day=thur
RewriteRule ^days/content\.php$ /thursday [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =day=fri
RewriteRule ^days/content\.php$ /friday [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =day=sat
RewriteRule ^days/content\.php$ /saturday [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =day=sun
RewriteRule ^days/content\.php$ /sunday [R=301,END]

# Rewrite new URLs
RewriteRule ^monday$ days/content.php?day=mon [END]
RewriteRule ^tuesday$ days/content.php?day=tue [END]
RewriteRule ^wednesday$ days/content.php?day=wed [END]
RewriteRule ^thursday$ days/content.php?day=thur [END]
RewriteRule ^friday$ days/content.php?day=fri [END]
RewriteRule ^saturday$ days/content.php?day=sat [END]
RewriteRule ^sunday$ days/content.php?day=sun [END]
```

It is best to do the days individually since the script uses a short form and the new URL doesn't. You can change them if needed, or let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Apache](http://ports.su/www/apache-httpd,-main) and [nginx](http://ports.su/www/nginx,-main) have the concept of ***internal*** and ***external*** redirects.

What you could do to accomplish your task is create a "redirect loop", where `/days/content.php?day=thur` would `redirect`/`R` (external redirect) to `/thursday`, whereas `/thursday` would internally go back to `/days/content.php?day=thur`, which may initially look like a loop.

See:

- [nginx redirect loop, remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687288/nginx-redirect-loop-remove-index-php-from-url)

This could be done by testing against the *request uri* in each case:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/days/content.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^day=thur$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /thursday? [R,L] # external redirect

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/thursday$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /days/content.php?day=thur [L] # internal redirect
```

Comment: this is good, the url in the browser shows `dundaah.com/thursday` but doesn't show content just `dundaah.com redirected you too many times` and that i should try clearing my cookies but even after i did, still got the same message. the internal links still remain `days/content.php?day=thur` for the index page and `content.php?day=thur` for files inside the `days` folder, which are just two `content.php & contact.php`. i don't have any code that removes the `.php` extention.

Comment: @MaxNjoroge, did you make sure to have only one `R`?  It sounds like you are creating an actual loop by having external redirects in each case, instead of having an internal one in the other one.

Comment: You can't use "REQUEST_URI" as that is updated by rewrites. What you could use is "THE_REQUEST" which is the original request and doesn't get modified. Or just use [END] as I have in my answer, so no more processing is done by mod_rewrite after a successful match.