# Treat more than one php file as directory, htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

I am new to htaccess files, and I understand how to do basic rewrites of URLs such as removing index.php, extensions, etc. I am also able to use  $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] to work with anything trailing the file.

What I struggle with is how it would be possible to do this with a trailing faux-directory structure on another file other than the (not-shown) index.php. Lets say I have

```
domain.com/render.php/this
```

and I want it to read

```
domain.com/render/this
```

My workaround is currently to do all my logic in my index.php file, but I would like to break it up into several files, so that I would have `index.php` doing my home-page stuff, and `render.php` something completely different.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Can't test it right now, and I am not all that familiar with PI, but doesn't do `RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/(.*)$ $1.php/$2 [L]` do the job? You might need to use the `DPI` flag.

Comment: thanks for the eventual upvote+accept!  +1 goes to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your overall directory structure.  Take a look at [Apache .htaccess to hide both .php and .html extentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591251/apache-htaccess-to-hide-both-php-and-html-extentions/15591353#15591353), for example.

If you already have `/render/this` configured to go to `/render.php/this`, and all you have to do is perform redirection the other way, then try this:

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \b\.php\b
RewriteRule ^([^/.])\.php/(.*)$ $1/$2   [R]
```

(The `\b` part *matches at a word boundary*, as per [`pcrepattern(3)`](http://mdoc.su/n/pcrepattern.3), which is from the [`pcre`](http://ports.su/devel/pcre) library that both [Apache `httpd`](http://ports.su/www/apache-httpd) as well as [`nginx`](http://ports.su/www/nginx) use in support of regular expressions.)

Comment: heh, i think there is a typo in my regex above -- `([^/.])` should probably be `([^/.]+)`.